# SSRS Get previous value in row group

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, ssrs-2014

I have A tablex which has row grouping , trying to do some calculation base on the previous row in the group. so I tested `Last(Fields!InQty.Value)` and put it in the total cell. and it get the value of the same row :

[image]

When I tried `Previous(Fields!InQty.Value)` it get the value from the last row in the previous group :

[image]

so what is the way to get the previous value in the same group, also how to check if the row is the first in the group. 
Thank you.

Comment: I have always assumed that the Previous function in SSRS had an optional scope parameter; alas, no. Shows how often I make use of it. You may have to think about doing this calculation in the dataset SQL.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0251ad79-c1b9-4a34-a32f-64e5ea7561a1/runningvalue-in-a-matrix?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could just wrap inside an `IF` statement, perhaps as follows:

`=IIF(Previous(Fields!ItemName.Value)=Fields!ItemName.Value,Previous(Fields!InQty.Value),Nothing)`

...Or replace the `Nothing` with some constant if it's part of a larger calculation expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in SSRS to do this is to use the RowNumber value for the group the cell is in (I'm calling it "Item" in the example below), and check that the RowNumber value for the group is greater than 1 before collecting the previous value.  If it isn't greater than 1 you can put Nothing in the table cell:

```
=Iif(RowNumber("Item") > 1, Previous(Fields!InQty.Value), Nothing)
```